# Ajax updating database when a checkbox is checked

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Hi I am trying to update a database table by clicking on a checkbox but it's not working.

HTML:

```
<input name="no_cage" id="no_cage" type="checkbox" value="1" onclick="chkit(<?php echo $estimate_id; ?>,'no_cage');" <?php echo $checked; ?>
```

AJAX:

```
function chkit(estimate_id, no_cage) {
    chk=document.getElementById("no_cage").checked;

    $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'ajax.php',
            data: { chkYesNo: no_cage, estimate_id: estimate_id}

        });
}
```

ajax.php

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/dbconnect.php");

$get=$_GET['chkYesNo'];

$get_id=$_GET['estimate_id'];
if($get=="1")
{
    $sql = "UPDATE estimates SET
            no_cage = '1',
            cage_linear_feet = '',
            cage_doors = '',
            cage_options = '',
            cage_labor = ''
            WHERE estimate_id = '".$get_id."'";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
}
else
{

}
?>
```

Can anyone see what is I'm missing? I am no expert and have been playing around with the for quite a while with no luck.

Thanks,

John

Comment: What do you see when you Echo your SQL statement?

Comment: Is the sql statement valid (column names etc)? Do you get the values in your script ok?

Comment: SQL statement is fine. I have browsed to ajax.php and passed the variables as per the following and it worked fine - ajax.php?estimate_id=4&chkYesNo=1

Comment: Maybe you should try adding a `.done` and `.fail` method to your javsscript then you might know what s happening

Comment: @RiggsFolly where would I include those in the JS? I am no expert on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are passing `'no_cage'` as parameter 2 of your

```
onclick="chkit(<?php echo $estimate_id; ?>,'no_cage');"
```

And then passing that to the PHP, via AJAX as

```
data: { chkYesNo: no_cage, estimate_id: estimate_id}
        ^^^^^^^^
```

When you get to the PHP code `$get` will be `= no_cage` and never as your PHP code expects it to be i.e. `1`

```
$get=$_GET['chkYesNo'];   // which will = `no_cage'`

if($get=="1")
```

So in short, you are never actually running the query

Also try this when finding if the checkbox is checked as your code will return `true` or `false` which may be causing the issue

```
function chkit(estimate_id, no_cage) {
    chk = document.getElementById("no_cage").checked ? 1 : 0;

    $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'ajax.php',
            data: { chkYesNo: chk, estimate_id: estimate_id}

        });
}
```

Comment: I have amended the code above. I only need to pass the estimate_id and nothing else.

Comment: You are not supposed to change questions once a useful answer has been given. All that does is make those answers look like nonsense

Comment: If necessary ask another question after attempting a bit more debugging yourself

Comment: Sorry - I didn't think of that. I am still at a loss though as it's not working.

Comment: See extra bit I added on the end of the answer

Comment: I tried that extra code and still not working unfortunately. Thanks for being so persistant.

Comment: Ignore me - that does work. Brilliant! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

corrects the value of the variable **chkYesNo** , 
you must place the var **chk** for example

```
if(chk){
  chk=1
}else{
  chk=0
 }
```

data:

> { chkYesNo: chk, estimate_id: estimate_id}