# use checkbox with ajax to update database

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So, I am try to update the fields in my database (id[int], status[boolean]) using a checkbox with Ajax. This should be done without refreshing the page and not using a submit button. I have tried multiple tutorials and non seems to work for me. To name a few:
[Ajax updating database when a checkbox is checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39333365/ajax-updating-database-when-a-checkbox-is-checked),
[checkbox on change ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26065161/checkbox-on-change-ajax-call/26066137),
[update database with checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18705369/update-database-with-checkbox)

Please I really need help with this one been on this for days.
This is my attempt at it:

#### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <input type="checkbox" name="action1" id="action1" title="Action 1" value="1"/>
  
<script type="text/javascript">
 $("#action1").change(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "update.php",
        async: true,
        data: {
            action1: value // as you are getting in php $_POST['action1'] 
        },
        success: function (msg) {
            alert('Success');
            if (msg != 'success') {
                alert('Fail');
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

#### update.php

```
 <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "api";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
//echo "Connected successfully";

 if($_POST['action1']==1){  //as used variable name "value" in ajax post data
          $sql = "UPDATE toggle SET status = '1' WHERE id = '1'"; //query was incomplete and missing ";"
          
          echo 'success';
     }
     else{
          $sql = "UPDATE toggle SET status = '0' WHERE id = '1'"; // missing ";"
          
          echo 'success';
     }
     $result=$conn->query($sql);
?>
```

Comment: All you've done is post your code, but we don't know what issue you're facing.  Are you getting an error?  If so, what is it and at what point do you see it?

Comment: Sorry my bad, yeah when first check value get update for status to '1' with the alert('Success') but the followed with alert('Fail') , when unchecked  get same messages but the value is not updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your update file returns 'success' no matter what data is sent to it.  Try it this way:

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <input type="checkbox" name="action1" id="action1" title="Action 1" value="2"/>Action
  
<script type="text/javascript">
 $("#action1").change(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "update.php",
        async: true,
        data: {
            action1: value // as you are getting in php $_POST['action1'] 
        },
        success: function (msg) {
                alert(msg);
        }
    });
});
</script>
</body>
```

**update.php**

```
 <?php
 $servername = "localhost";
 $username = "root";
 $password = "";
 $database = "stackoverflow";
 // Create connection
 $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

 // Check connection
 if ($conn->connect_error) {
   die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 }
  if($_POST['action1']==1){
      $sql = "UPDATE toggle SET status = '1' WHERE id = '1'";
      
      echo 'success';
 }
 else{
      $sql = "UPDATE toggle SET status = '0' WHERE id = '1'";
      
      echo 'fail';
 }
 $result=$conn->query($sql);
 ?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it produces the same result. The 'if' SQL query seems to get executed but for some reason the 'else' does not. I don't know why this is happening.

Comment: You need to give it a reason to produce something else.  The form check you have sends action1: 1, so update it to send 2, or whatever you like.

Comment: you mean something like else if $_POST['action1']==2)?

Comment: No, I mean in your html form, change the checkbox value: <input type="checkbox" name="action1" id="action1" title="Action 1" value="2"/>

Comment: Yeah still no luck. Thank you for helping, I really appreciate. Maybe, I should try to find another tutorial on this any recommendation?

Comment: What do you mean no luck?  I updated my answer to show to the full example, and this works for me

Comment: Sorry, did not the value properly. It works thank you very much.